# Reading child node from XML with same name using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

Consider the following XML.I want to read a particular child node value only, from a particular parent node.

```
**<response>
   <Statuses>
       <Detail>
           <number>123</number>
       </Detail>
       <ToDate>
           <date>1/1/2000</date>
       </ToDate>
       <FromDate>
           <date>1/1/2000</date>
       </FromDate>
   </Statuses>
</response>**
```

I want to read the date value from the "fromDate" tag and also the number from the details tag.

I tried ,

```
If(reader.name.Equals("Statuses"StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
dateValue=reader.GetAttribute("/FromDate/Date");
}
```

This does not work. Pls suggest.

Comment: Well you're not trying to read an attribute, you're trying to read an element - and that's not how you use `XmlReader`. I would *strongly* suggest that you use LINQ to XML - read the XML into an `XDocument`, then you can use `var date = doc.Root.Element("Statuses").Element("FromDate").Element("date");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jon Skeet you should really use LINQ to XML for these types of tasks.It would make your life easier:

**Sameple XML file:**

```
<response>
  <Statuses>
    <Detail>
      <number>123</number>
    </Detail>
    <ToDate>
      <date>1/1/2000</date>
    </ToDate>
    <FromDate>
      <date>1/1/2000</date>
    </FromDate>
  </Statuses>
  <Statuses>
    <Detail>
      <number>1234</number>
    </Detail>
    <ToDate>
      <date>1/1/2000</date>
    </ToDate>
    <FromDate>
      <date>1/1/2001</date>
    </FromDate>
  </Statuses>
</response>
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //If the xml file is in the solution - set Build Action of the file to "Embedded Resource" 
            //and Copy to Output Directory to "Copy always"
            var doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");

            doc.Element("response").Elements().ToList().ForEach(e =>
                {
                    string number = e.Element("Detail").Element("number").Value;
                    string date = e.Element("FromDate").Element("date").Value;

                    Console.WriteLine("Number - {0}.Date - {1}\n", number, date);
                });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output in Visual Studio]

Comment: When i "ToList" the above , I do get values. When I "ForEach" on it, it throws an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. I tried checking if the value is null before assigning it. Did not work.

Comment: 1)Copy the input file exactly as it is in my answer2)Copy the code exactly as it is in my answer.